# How to make AFNetworking show plain HTTP response error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, afnetworking

I'm trying to send some information from my app to my PHP server side program.

When I try to send the same data using the `PHP Array` as UnitTest it works. So I dont know why AFNeworking is thinking that this doesnt work.

In order to debug the problem i need to be able to see the full HTTP message.

How could I see the plain(NON-JSON) error (the HTTP response)?

I though that `operation.JSONReadingOptions = NSJSONReadingAllowFragments;` would do the trick, but is not working or i am not placing it in the right place

Thanks

**My error:**

```
2013-06-05 10:52:37.990 iGym[9407:c07]Request failed with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Garbage at end.) UserInfo=0x96db4d0 {NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}, {
NSDebugDescription = "Garbage at end.";
```

}

**My Objective-c code**

```
User* myUser = [self getCurrentUser];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://192.168.1.64/"];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:url];

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"register":@"true",
                             @"email":@"as234d",
                             @"userID":(myUser.idUserExternal ? myUser.idUserExternal: @"NO"),
                             @"userDetails":@{@"needUsername":(myUser.nickname ? @"NO": @"YES"),
                                              @"username":( myUser.nickname  ? myUser.nickname : _input.text),
                                              @"language":(myUser.language? myUser.language: @"0"),
                                              @"name":(myUser.name ? myUser.name : @"0"),
                                              @"surname":(myUser.surname ? myUser.surname : @"0"),
                                              @"country":(myUser.country ? myUser.country : @"0"),
                                              @"dob":(myUser.dob ? myUser.dob : @"0"),
                                              @"city":(myUser.city ? myUser.city : @"0"),
                                              @"height":(myUser.height ? myUser.height : @"0"),
                                              @"weight":(myUser.weight ? myUser.weight : @"0"),
                                              @"metricType":(myUser.metricSystem ? myUser.metricSystem : @"0")
                                            }
                             };
    NSLog(@"%@",params);
    NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"igym/bootstrap.php" parameters:params];


    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                                        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON){
                                                                                            NSLog(@"Inside the success block %@",JSON);
                                                                                            if ([JSON objectForKey:@"ok"]) {
                                                                                                [self done:JSON];
                                                                                            }

                                                                                            if ([JSON objectForKey:@"error"]) {
                                                                                                [self tryAgain:JSON[@"error"]];
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){

                                                               NSLog(@"json text is: %@", JSON);
                                                                                            NSLog(@"Request failed with error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                                                                                        }];
    operation.JSONReadingOptions = NSJSONReadingAllowFragments;

    [operation start];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `success` or `error` block, you can `NSLog` `operation.responseString` or `operation.responseData`. That will give you the raw string or bytes sent from the server.

Comment: I am doing it inside the Error block as t he success block is not being executed and i cant see the full http error doing `NSLog(@"%",operation.responseData)`

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"%@", operation.responseString)`

Comment: @mattt What is the proper way to access the responseData in case of an error with AFNetworking 2.0?